# Django: why does reverse of OneToOneField return a tuple?

Tags: python, django, tuples, one-to-one

I have a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) field in my model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

elsewhere in a view, I am trying to get the `Portfolio` from a `User`

`portfolio = request.user.portfolio`

My debugger shows the result as this: `<class 'tuple'>: (<Portfolio: 9999999>,)`

Why is it doing this? Shouldn't 1 to 1 return a single object?

Comment: It returns a single model instance for me. Are you using a custom model manager?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a trailing comma after `portfolio = request.user.portfolio`. That would turn it into a tuple.

Comment: You should show how you are using this; you've probably put a stray trailing comma somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just experienced the same error. As Daniel suggested it was a trailing comma behind a field in my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Name')
    author = models.OneToOneField('Author'), # <----- this comma was the cause of all evil
```